How to get the average
What is the proper formula for getting the average handling time on the form that I'm creating.
I got the formula on counting the True and False date on separate dates, but I can't get the Average of AHT.

=COUNTIFS(B:B, "TRUE", C:C, ">=21/10/2024", C:C, "<=25/10/2024")

=COUNTIFS(B:B, "FALSE", C:C, ">=21/10/2024", C:C, "<=25/10/2024")

=AVERAGEIFS (B:B, C:C, ">=21/10/2024", C:C, "<=25/10/2024")




What is the proper formula for calculating the average value of multiple cells?

AHT seems to be Column_H or so; however within averageifs the range to be averaged is pointing to Column_B

I already change it to "H" =AVERAGEIFS (B:B, H:H, ">=21/10/2024", H:H, "<=25/10/2024") but shows #DIV/0!

So now you have dates in Column_H?

Oh I see now, I got confused. I change it again to =AVERAGEIFS (H:H, C:C, ">=21/10/2024", C:C, "<=25/10/2024") but still has the same issue

Do you have values in Column_H that can eventually be averaged?!
